# Pulling specific parts of multiple strings located in an array.

Tags: python, arrays, string

I am trying to pull the first number within a record (wins-losses-ties) for each record that is being kept within an array. For example:

The array could be the following: [2-2-3, 4-5-2, 1-3-8].

Considering I want to pull all of the values for the number of wins and assign them to a new array, the array that I would like to end up with is the following [2, 4, 1].

how could i do this within my python code?

Thanks.

Comment: what's `2-2-3`? Is it supposed to be `'2-2-3'`?

Answer (score 2):

```
result = next(zip(*[(2,2,3), (4,5,2), (1,3,8)]))
```

Or, if the records are actually strings:

```
result = next(zip(*(data.split('-') for data in ['2-2-3', '4-5-2', '1-3-8'])))
```

Explanation:

```
>>> list(zip(*[(2,2,3), (4,5,2), (1,3,8)]))
[(2, 4, 1), (2, 5, 3), (3, 2, 8)]
```

You want to get the first element, so you could do `list(zip(*[(2,2,3), (4,5,2), (1,3,8)]))[0]`, but this isn't necessary since `zip` constructs its return values on-the-fly, and doesn't calculate all of them at once (so it doesn't waste memory), so you can make it generate and return *only* the first value with `next(zip(...))`.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: @Ayxan, yes, absolutely. I've added an explanation

Comment: Thanks for fixing it

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
arr = ['2-2-3', '4-5-2', '1-3-8']
result = [s.split('-')[0] for s in arr]
```

**Explanation:**

```
[s for s in arr]
# output: ['2-2-3', '4-5-2', '1-3-8']

[s.split('-') for s in arr]
# output: [['2', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '2'], ['1', '3', '8']]

[s.split('-')[0] for s in arr]
# output: ['2', '4', '1']
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Just beat me to the answer. I was gonna put in the same lol.

Explanation: 
loop over the list elements; 
split it on the separator, i.e., '-' and; 
store the first element of the resulting splitted string to the final result list